# for loop exection using bash script

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have the following for loop

```
 for ((i=0;i<=110;i++))
 do
   j=0.01
   k="$(echo "$i"*"$j" | bc)"
   l=((k+900))
   echo "$l"
 done
```

When I am running this code, it gives following error:

```
line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 5: `l=((k+900))'
line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
line 7: `done'
```

Please guide me through the error. Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace `((k+900))` with `$((k+900))`.

Comment: I did as told by you. Now it gives me following error:                                line 5: .01: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ".01")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

- You need to replace the arithmetic operation, `((k+900))`, with arithmetic expansion to save the output in a variable:

  ```
  l=$((k+900))
  ```
- Secondly, `bash` can not do floating point arithmetic, so as the variable `k` contains floating point number the addition would result in syntax error. You need to replace `bash`'s arithmetic with `bc` (inside command substitution):

  ```
  l=$(echo "$k +900" | bc)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One note, you can do these types of loops much easier in bash. Also since bash doesn't support floats, I would just call python and write something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..110}; do
    j="0.01"
    k="$(python -c "print($i * $j)")"
    l="$(python -c "print($k + 900)")"
    echo "$l"
done
```